# How to name methods that may or may not take action?

Tags: naming-conventions

I'm always unsure as to how to name a method that has logic to essentially do nothing if a state is not met. For example

```
 private int addFive(int num){
     if(num==0){
         return num;
     }

     return num+5;
 }
```

Reading the method you assume you give it a number and it returns it with 5 added. However this will not happen if it is 0. I do not think addFiveIfNotZero() is a great name. I had a colleague who suggested using the term "fill" as she has heard it used sometimes in this context. I was curious if there was a standard or practice out there.

Comment: Why are you naming methods after their effect instead of after their purpose?

Comment: The question as it is is somewhat tough to answer.  If you had an actual real world use case, I suspect the answers would range anywhere from a simple rename to a refactor of the entire method.

Comment: Real world is adding 30 minutes to a time if the user has the time set to more than 0. addBuffer either adds the buffer or if it is set to 0, does not add anything.

Answer (score 0):

Readability is very important in code we write, especially for others. In this case since you dislike the name 'addFiveIfNotZero', you might want to remove this method or group it with some other function if it is too granular.

I've found that naming a method by the business feature proves very useful to the reader.

Another option could be 'addFiveIfNonZero'.